# How Should I write this Tensor Product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

I want to prove that every element of $M \otimes_R R$ is of the form $m \otimes_R 1$, given that $M$ is a unital $R$-module.

I took $x$ as an element of $M \otimes_R R$ and wrote $x = m \otimes_R r = mr \otimes_R 1$, but I got stuck.

I would appreciate it if you guys could help me understand this and show me how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to demonstrate the isomorphism $M \otimes_R R \cong M$ as $R$-modules? Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: @SammyBlack I simply want to prove that M$⊗_{R}$R is of the form m$⊗_{R}$1. I don't know which of the two approaches I took is the right approach. And I would like to know how to progress.

Comment: You seem to have some confusion between the set $M \otimes_R R$ and the elements of that set.  For instance, you write "$M \otimes_R R = \sum r_i(m_i \otimes n_i)$ for all $r_i \in R, n_i \in R, m_i \in M, i \in N$"  What does this mean?  My best guess is that your goal is to show that every element of $M \otimes_R R$ is of the form $m \otimes 1$ for some $m \in M$.  Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I want to prove that every element of M$⊗_{R}$R is of the form m$⊗_{R}$1